# AJAX: Loading URL on submit button clicked

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I am trying to load/redirect another page/site depending upon success or error. 
First thing it always executes error block, though I checked the console I could not find any error there. and 
Secondly it do not redirect to the URL specified with "windows.location.href('URL');"

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/AppBot/AnswerHandler',
            data: 'operation=login' + '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email,
            success: function() {
                alert('Success');
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Failure');
                window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
            }
        });
    });
});`

Comment: window.loaction.href should be window.location.href

Comment: ohh.. my bad. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your code as below to fix the typo error in `you had typo error in window.loaction.href`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login-form").on("submit", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();

        var request = $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/AppBot/AnswerHandler',
            //pass your data as an array
            data: { operation : 'login', name : name, email: email },
            beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
                //$('#loading').show();
            }
        });

        request.done(function( response ) {                

            console.info('Success');
            console.log(response);
        });

        request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            alert( "Color request failed: " + textStatus );
            window.location.href = 'https://www.google.com';
        });


    });
});
```

Comment: So now the first problem is solved. But It always executes error block.

Comment: Try passing data as an object using {operation:'login', name:name, email:email}

Comment: @SagarGalande I have updated the ajax code, try using this instead, check what you get in your console. And check the script that you are calling, it should return a json encoded data

Comment: @SagarGalande, what did you get in your console in firebug?

Comment: wait, I am trying this new script

Comment: Can you see the ajax request in firebug console, try clicking it and see what is passed in params and check the response for same. Paste it here. Is your http://localhost:8080/AppBot/AnswerHandler getting called?
try calling this url in your browser directly and see what response you get

Comment: sorry for late response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108402/discussion-between-sagar-galande-and-shivgre).

Comment: @SagarGalande that is the response from alert. Your url script is failing and  is either having a warning or something else. It should only return a json encoded array , try changing the dataType: 'html' then you should get the plain response but you still need to fix your called script

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#login-form").on("submit",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
       $.ajax({
          method: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:8080/AppBot/AnswerHandler",
          data: { operation: 'login', name: name, email:email}
        })
          .done(function( msg ) {
            alert('Success');
          });
    });
});
```

Comment: What I mean is the ajax executes the error block, though there is no error on console

Comment: use this dataType: 'json',

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108395/discussion-between-maulik-and-sagar-galande).

Comment: The second issue is solved, It was just a typo error. But the second one is not solved yet